# How to know whether filter is stable given in- and output shapes?

Tags: filter, stability

I have this filter with

$$H(z) = \frac1{0.5z^{-1}}$$

How can I know whether this filter is stable given that \$x(n) = a^nU(n)\$ and \$y(n) = -a^n U(-n-1)\$?

Comment: hey, it'll delight you to learn that you can directly use TeX syntax within your question; I've replaced your images that way. If you want to know how that works, click on the "edit" field to look at your question's source code.

Comment: Wouldn't \$ H(z) = \frac1{0.5z^{-1}} \rightarrow h[n] = 2 \delta[n+1]\$? So shouldn't \$ x[n] = a^n u[n]  \rightarrow y[n] = 2 a^{n+1} u[n+1]\$ ?

Comment: Also, stability is not a property of the input and output, but of the transfer-function itself. And in you case you are probably looking at if it is a BIBO stable system, but trying inputs will not be a very good test for stability. Check
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/472280/is-unstable-system-unstable-for-all-inputs/472737#comment1197411_472737